# How to access a previous row in pymssql in python?

Tags: python, pymssql

For example, if I iterate over a query using:

```
for row in cursor:
```

And I want to make a comparison like:

```
if row[0] == previousrow[0]:
     #do something
```

How can I actually access the previous row?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to access the previous row from your `for` loop, you could use the following code.

```
previousrow = None

for row in cursor:
    if (!(previousrow is None)):
        # do your comparison with previous row and row here
    previousrow = row
```

I don't write Python, but I think this compiles and should work for you.